# Change background video when scrolling reaches a certain ID

Tags: javascript

My wordpress website is using a fixed section that contains a very light background video (it's just noise) that i want to change depending on which section the user is (it's a one-page scroller, but multiple sections). It's a video i uploaded on my wordpress and i use its link. How can i attain that please? I looked up some different previous threads but wasn't able to do this sadly, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean how can you obtain the link from code? Probably [wp_get_attachment_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/), and save the ID of the video or videos in get/set_option. Or did you mean how to write the URL into the page so that your scrolling JavaScript can find it, or something else?

Comment: @Rup Hey no sorry i mean i want to know how to make it so that the url of the video changes when the user is on a certain section (ID). Imagine if i'm on home i have one background video, but when i reach the second section (say Photos) the video changes (its url). Because the video is the background for my website and it's fixed, but the content is scrollable.